# How to generate a random tree (data structure) given some parameters?

Tags: algorithm, tree

I have to generate a random tree (the data structure, not the graphical one) given some parameters: at least the mean depth and the mean number of children of the nodes (as floats). There is no other contrainst (for now at least).

I really don't know this field so maybe there is something obvious I missed when I googled but I couldn't find anything... Maze generation algorithms looked interesting but they don't have these parameters as far as I can tell.

So please, tell me if this is possible at all, and if it is, give me some pointers, or even keywords to search for.

Thanks

Comment: Try pointing your favourite search engine at *stochastic l-system*.  (That's a letter `l` not a digit `1`.)

Answer (score -1):

You can start by creating procedure *gen*, creating the tree with given height and random number of children on each level *avgChildCount*. The number of children is selected in range of:

```
[0, (avgChildCount*2).toInt]
```

So, when you have this procedure you can introduce another one, taking two averages *avgHeight* and *avgChildCount* calling *gen*:

```
gen(random(0, (avgHeight*2).toInt), avgChildCount)
```